# Get identical elements and index from 2 Arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, indexing, comparison

I am new in Perl and I am trying to solve the following comparison.

I have two arrays:
@A = ("Red", "Green", "Yellow");
@B = ("Yellow", "Black","Yellow","Red", "White", "Yellow");

In array A, each element occurs only once.
In array B, each element can occur zero, one or many times.

For every element in A, the code should lists the position at which it is present in B and give the output as following:

`>` Red at index 3.
`>` Green is missing.
`>` Yellow at index 0, 2 and 5.
`>` Elements from B were detected 4 times in A.

I tried the following but I cannot figure out how to list indexes of elements after comparing two arrays

```
foreach $x (@A){
    foreach $y (@B){
    if ($y eq $x){
    print "$y\n";
    }
    elsif ($x ne$y){
    print "$x";
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please, help me? Thank you very much in advance!
Rebi

Comment: Crossposted to [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11100573).

Comment: A lot of people answered your question on PerlMonks. Yet you ask here exactly the same one, and don't seem to have made any effort to fix it by following the suggestions you were given on PerlMonks. So basically, you seem to be waiting for a solution matching exactly your requirements, rather than for help to solve your problem. If you want someone to do your code for you, you should hire a developer.

Comment: This sounds like a midterm

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
my @A = ("Red", "Green", "Yellow");
my @B = ("Yellow", "Black","Yellow","Red", "White", "Yellow");
my %indices;
for my $i (0..$#B) {
    push @{ $indices{$B[$i]} }, $i;
}
my $count = 0;
for (@A) {
    if (exists $indices{$_} ) {
        my @temp = @{ $indices{$_} };
        $count += (scalar @temp);
        print "$_ is at index: ", @temp, "\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$_ is missing\n";
    }
}
print "Elements from B were detected ", $count, " times in A.\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ll take a look to the "exists" function

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat simple way. A count and a switch variable keeps track of whether an item is found or missing:

```
my @a = ("Red", "Green", "Yellow");
my @b = ("Yellow", "Black","Yellow","Red", "White", "Yellow");
my $count = 0;
for my $ael (0 .. $#a) {
 my $switch = "off";
 for my $bel (00 .. $#b) {
  if ($a[$ael] eq $b[$bel]) {
  $count++;
  $switch = "on"; 
print "$b[$bel] found at index $bel\n";
                            }
                         }
print "$a[$ael] is missing\n" if $switch eq "off";  
                        }
print "Elements from B found $count times in A";
```

Outputs:

```
Red found at index 3
Green is missing
Yellow found at index 0
Yellow found at index 2
Yellow found at index 5
Elements from B found 4 times in A
```

Comment: Thanks! this is a great help for me